# Adding league s3 filesystem breaks auto loading

Tags: php, composer-php, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, guzzle

After adding the Leauge S3 filesystem adaptor I receive the following auto loading error on my EBS system.

<kbd>composer.json</kbd>

```
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.0",
    "slim/slim": "2.3.2",
    "slim/extras": "dev-develop",
    "twig/twig":  "1.*",
    "directus/migrations": "dev-master",
    "directus/permissions": "0.9.*@dev",
    "directus/database": "~0.1.3",
    "league/flysystem": "^1.0",
    "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^1.0",
    "swiftmailer/swiftmailer": "^5.4"   },
```

Error:

> Failed opening required
>   '/var/app/current/vendor/composer/../guzzlehttp/psr7/src/functions_include.php'
>   (include_path='/var/app/current/vendor/phpunit/php-token-stream:/var/app/current/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects:/var/app/current/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage:/var/app/current/vendor/phpunit/phpunit:/var/app/current/vendor/symfony/yaml:.:/usr/share/pear7:/usr/share/php7')
>   in /var/app/current/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 70

Answer (score 0):

try updating composer with

`>composer self-update`

You can also clear the cache of composer launching the command:

`>composer clear-cache`

Hope this help